# Why am I getting segmentation fault in my following C code?

Tags: c

This is a problem from spoj named prime1. The code seems to be correct to me. This even runs and produces desirable results on ideone.com but spoj gives me a runtime error, saying this is a segmentation fault. I can't find any memory leaks, no buffer overflow, etc. Please help me find the segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned int arr[32200];

int prime()
{
    unsigned int i,j,k=2;
    int flag;
    arr[0]=2;
    arr[1]=3;
    for (i=5;i<32200;i+=2)
    {
         flag=0;
         for(j=3;j<i;j+=2)
         {
             if(i%j==0)
             {
                 flag=1;
                 break;
             }
         }
         if (flag==0)
         {
             arr[k++]=i;
         }
     }
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int t;
    unsigned int a,b,i,m;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    prime();
    while(t--)
    {
         scanf("%u%u",&a,&b);
         for(i=0;;i++)
         {
             if (arr[i]>=a)
             {
                 m=i;
                 break;
             }
         }
         while(arr[m]<=b)
         {
             printf("%u\n",arr[m]);
             m++;
         }
         printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the program do? Can you indent it and give the variables meaningful names?

Comment: Might I suggest printing some of your variables? Like t, a, b, i, m, k, j. There are several places where an incorrect value of these could lead to a seg fault. However, without me knowing what these are or the purpose of the code, I can't tell you if they'll ever be incorrect.

Comment: This program is written for computers, not for humans. I guess its intention is to train people to work like state machines, which I don't want to do. John Kugelman is completely right. It does not make sense nor fun to analyze such a bad code.

Comment: Instead of putting huge amount of data on the stack (32200 ints), use malloc and friends instead.

Comment: I bet the huge int array allocated on stack is the reason.

Comment: At least tell us what input you're passing!

Comment: @FredrikPihl That data is not on the stack, it's in static storage - it's a global variable.

Comment: @Ashalynd There is no array allocated on the stack, see the last comment.

Answer (score 2):

If an `a` is given that is greater than all elements in `arr`, the first `for()` loop in `main()` overruns the array, yielding undefined behavior. The fact that the global variable `arr` will be zero initialized helps to trigger this condition: start with any `a` other than zero, and you immediately have undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. So bad I couldn't find this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The array you are keeping your primes is too small.

The maximum number you can have as `b` is `10^9` and the smallest for `a` is 1. Therefore, you need to store all primes between 1 and one billion.

If you type "how many primes between 1 and 1000000000" in wolfram alpha, for instance, you will get that there are `50847534` primes between those two. So your array is too small.

Also, after you fix that, you're getting a TLE. Your code is too inefficient for this problem. You need to develop a faster method to generate the prime numbers.